# Fresh install of SQLSERVER 2008 r2 Express, what's my server name?

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, sql-server-2008-r2

See this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpj52.jpg

It's a fresh Win7 install, fresh 2008 r2 install.  For the life of me I can't work out what to enter as server name, I've tried:

```
TOM
Localhost
SQLEXPRESS
```

All fail.  Can someone help me?

Also, in SQL Server Config Manager I seem to have lots of stopped (duplicate?) services.  Is this normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your screen shot appears as though you have two named instances installed on this server -- SQLEXPRESS and TOM.

In the "Server Name" field: `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` will connect to the "SQLEXPRESS" instance and `localhost\TOM` will connect to the "TOM" instance.

Comment: localhost\SQLEXPRESS works fine, thanks!  When I initially installed it it failed 1/2 way through because the PC needed to reset to install a windows update, this is probably why 2 instances are installed?  I find the setup programs pretty confusing for this, any tips on how to uninstall the second instance?

Comment: In the Control Panel, select "Uninstall a Program".  You should see "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2", right-click and select "Uninstall/Change".  Follow the installation wizard, it should detect all instances and prompt you select the one to remove.